# How to disable bootstrap 4 modal on mobile in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am generating modals dynamically in Wordpress like so:

```
<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-'. get_the_ID() .'" class="text-center">
<img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id) . '" class="img-fluid position-relative mx-auto">
    <h3 class="artist-title text-center w-100 position-absolute align-self-end pb-2">'. get_the_title() .'</h3>
</a>
```

And want to disable, for instance, `data-toggle="modal"` so that the modal won't work on mobile and uses the href to go to the content.

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed it with the following:

```
var width = $(window).width();  
if(width < 480){
$('.mdl').removeAttr('data-toggle');
}
```

Don't know if this is the best solution though.

Comment: You could use javascript to only bind the modal-opening-process if it's really needed and would get rid of  the "data-toggle" and "data-target"-attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Like I commented - I'd get rid of the data attributes first:

```
<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" class="text-center">
```

Then use Javascript to open the modal only if your viewport-width is larger than 400px:

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(window.innerWidth > 400){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal-XXX').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Aah oké. So you would go the other way around, kind of. Instead of disabling it on mobile tell the DOM to use it on larger screens only. The thing is though, that `#modal-XXX` is dynamic